# ObjectAnimator not working with parameter passed as a variable

Tags: android, objectanimator

I have a situation where I'm animating an ImageView with the ObjectAnimator class.  I'm translating the ImageView along the Y axis by the view's height property.  I store its height property in a variable called "menuHeight".  When I translate the view upward using this variable (menuHeight * -1), it works fine.  When I attempt to translate it backward using the same variable (minus converting it to a negative), however, it doesn't do anything.  If I hard-code the height value (in this case, 659) it works.

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView menu;
    Button slideUpButton;
    Button slideDownButton;
    float menuHeight;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        menu = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.menuView);
        slideUpButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.slideUpButton);
        slideDownButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.slideDownButton);

       menu.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menucropped);

        //This works
        final ObjectAnimator slideUpTranslate = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(menu,View.TRANSLATION_Y, menuHeight * -1);
        slideUpTranslate.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());

        //This does nothing
        final ObjectAnimator slideDownTranslate = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(menu,View.TRANSLATION_Y, menuHeight);
        slideDownTranslate.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());


        slideUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                slideUpTranslate.start();
                Log.i("Test", "Slide up clicked...  Height:" + Float.toString(menuHeight));
            }
        });

        slideDownButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                slideDownTranslate.start();
                Log.i("Test","Slide down clicked...  Height:" + Float.toString(menuHeight));
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){
        menuHeight=menu.getHeight();
        menu.setTranslationY(menuHeight);
    }

}
```

So, long story short, this doesn't work:

```
final ObjectAnimator slideDownTranslate = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(menu,View.TRANSLATION_Y, menuHeight);
```

But this does:

```
final ObjectAnimator slideDownTranslate = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(menu,View.TRANSLATION_Y, 659);
```

And this does as well:

```
final ObjectAnimator slideUpTranslate = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(menu,View.TRANSLATION_Y, menuHeight * -1);
```

I've confirmed through the log that the variable isn't getting changed at any point after it gets initialized with the height value.  Why would passing the translation value in as a variable work in one but not the other?  Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 0):

You never initialized

```
float menuHeight;
```

how is this code not raising any error flags in your IDE?
A lot of new devices can show multiple windows, so onWindowFocusChanged() might not be called, so the menuHeight variable wouldn't be initialized.

Comment: True, I'll need to find a better solution for getting the height value of the ImageView (I couldn't get it to work in the onCreate call, getHeight() always returns 0).  That said, within the scope of this test activity, it should be working; it worked for the upward translate, after all?

Comment: @Brett for the upward translate, you do a multiplication op, I think when you do a native op on an uninitialized native value, it initialized it for you, I'm guessing it's initializing it to 0 and multiplying it by -1.

I might be wrong, been ages since I thought about how Java works.

Comment: According to the log, it initializes to 659 without a problem. It works if I do "-menuHeight" as well, instead of the multiplicative operation. I'm logging the variable's value on every button press (for both buttons), and it always reads 659, which is what it should be.